# Не отображаются данные fxml файла в модальном окне JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

```
public class MainWindowController {
  public void food(ActionEvent event) {
    Parent root = null;
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/addSpendAmount.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    createWindow(root, stage);
    stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
    stage.show();
}

private void createWindow(Parent root, Stage stage) {
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 150));
    stage.setTitle("Введите потраченую сумму");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
}
```

/fxml/addSpendAmount.fxml

```
<Pane fx:controller="controllers.addSpendAmountController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
  <TextField fx:id="indicateCost" layoutX="184.0" layoutY="188.0" />
  <Button layoutX="384.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveCost" text="Готово" />
  </children>
   </Pane>
```

controllers.addSpendAmountController.class

```
public class addSpendAmountController {

public void saveCost(ActionEvent event) {
}
```

При нажатии кнопки `food` в главном окне, срабатывает одноименный метод в классе `MainWindowContrller`, в этом методе создается новое окно, но элементов, которые я прописал в `fxml`-файле, нет, т.е. создается пустое окно. Из-за чего это происходит?

Отредактированный код:

```
public void food(ActionEvent event) {

    createWindow(event);

}

private void createWindow(ActionEvent event) {
    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/addSpendAmount.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 150));
    stage.setTitle("Введите потраченую сумму");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Для начала перенеси инициализацию элемента root в метод createWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что окно было слишком маленькое и элементов не было видно))

Answer (score 0):

В методе новое окно создается, но fxml файл не загружается. Нужно перенести загрузку fxml в обработчик нажатия кнопки. И инициализацию Stage туда же.

```
public void food() {

    createWindow();

}

@FXML
private void createWindow() {
    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/addSpendAmount.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 150));
    stage.setTitle("Введите потраченую сумму");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Отредактировал код, но результат все тот же. Исправленный код выше

Comment: А названия fxml файлов точно соответствуют? Я вижу зaгружается addSpendAmount.fxml , а что за файл /addSpendAmountController.fxml ???

Comment: Я ошибся в написании. addSpendAmount.fxml ссылается на addSpendAmountController.class. Названия все совпадают

Comment: ActionEvent там вообще не нужен. Зачем он вообще передается в в метод createWindow? Аннотируй метод food @FXML

Comment: Я дополнил свой ответ кодом

Comment: Мой код абсолютно повторяет ваш, но fxml файл по какой то причине не загружается. Я проверил все зависимости файлов и классов. Уже не представляю где может быть ошибка.